# Can you run all 0x.js libs from a browser environment?

Tags: 0x

We're in a Next.js app and attempting to use the client to generate signed messages from Orders. However, we're getting compile errors where it seems as though the lib requires the filesystem

```
Module not found: Can't resolve 'fs'
Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/rustbn.js/index.js
./node_modules/@0x/base-contract/node_modules/ethereumjs-vm/dist/evm/precompiles/06-ecadd.js
./node_modules/@0x/base-contract/node_modules/ethereumjs-vm/dist/evm/precompiles/index.js
./node_modules/@0x/base-contract/node_modules/ethereumjs-vm/dist/state/stateManager.js
./node_modules/@0x/base-contract/node_modules/ethereumjs-vm/dist/state/index.js
./node_modules/@0x/base-contract/node_modules/ethereumjs-vm/dist/index.js
./node_modules/@0x/base-contract/lib/src/index.js
./node_modules/0x.js/lib/index.js
./utils/contractUtils.ts
```

Am I missing something fundamental about this tutorial?

https://github.com/0xProject/wiki/blob/master/tutorials/1-Create%2C-Validate%2C-Fill-Order.md

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of Trader SDK for a more front-end friendly set up.

https://docs.swapsdk.xyz/